# c# make all elements in array without space

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this problem that CANT be solved with a cicle. (else I wouldn't be asking)
I have a array of strings, each storing different strings.
example of the things inside: "EC > TP > UK" , AN > ZX", etc.

i know the .replace thing you can do with a string.
Is there anything like that for string array?
this is what i have:

```
public static string[] dep1 = dep_p.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToArray<string>();
        public static string[] dep =
```

i need that dep is equal to dep1 but the elements don't have blank spaces in between each other, for example

if dep1 one has in, lest say, dep1[1] = "EC > AK > OT", i want dep[1] to be = "EC>AK>OT".

Regardless, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dep = dep1.Select(s => s.Replace(" ", "")).ToArray();
```

If it's a little bit more complicated because the tokens itself could contain spaces like `E C > AK > O  T` and you want to remove them, so still get `EC>AK>OT` as result:

```
dep = dep1.Select(
    s => string.Join(">", s.Split(new[] { '>' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                           .Select(t => t.Replace(" ", ""))))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Moreover, you could insert the `Select()` call in between the original `Where()` and `ToArray()`, and thus save the computer a bunch of cpu and memory.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: probably, but i don't know why OP needs 3 collections, maybe there is a reason